# opencv - remove all the yellow color from an image

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to remove a certain color from an image using cvInRangeS.
I've followed through this [tutorial](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/), however my returned mask seems to be holding only 0 values. Here's a copy of my code:

```
-(IplImage*)removeBackgroundLinear:(IplImage*) inImg{
    IplImage *imgHSV =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(inImg), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor(inImg, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

    IplImage* mask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(inImg), 8, 1);
    cvZero(mask);

    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), mask);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
    return mask;
}
```

What could be causing this? Of course, I'm trying my code against an image with yellow objects inside.

Thanks.

Comment: There may be some problem with your input image, because when I ran your code, it is giving me correct output. What is the data type of your input image?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the yellow range

try this :

`cvScalar(25, 80, 80,80), cvScalar(34, 255, 255,255)`

and you can use any program to get the color you need like `colorpicker.exe`